# Hide side navigationbar on certain pages/components in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, hide, navbar, jhipster

I'm currently working on a webapplication while using Jhipster and of course Angular.
I've created a side navbar and there also is a navbar on the top of every page.
Right now I'm trying to hide the side navbar at all on certain pages and I've now idea how to do that.

I'm using the latest version of JHipster and Angular 4.

```html
<nav>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul id="side_nav">
                    <li class="test"><a href="#"><img src="../../../content/images/icons8-home-50.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="project" routerLinkActive="active">Project Details</a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="asset" routerLinkActive="active">Asset</a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="threat" routerLinkActive="active">Threats</a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="attack-tree-node" routerLinkActive="active">Attack-Tree</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
      'sidenav.scss'
  ]
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do this, is to get the current path thanks to `Router` and `Location` of Angular in the constructor, and then, simply use `*ngIf` to show or not the side bar, for the path you want.

**sidenav.component.html**

```
<nav *ngIf="path==='/asset'">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul id="side_nav">
                    <li class="test"><a href="#"><img src="../../../content/images/icons8-home-50.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="project" routerLinkActive="active">Project Details</a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="asset" routerLinkActive="active">Asset</a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="threat" routerLinkActive="active">Threats</a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="attack-tree-node" routerLinkActive="active">Attack-Tree</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

**sidenav.component.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
path = '';
  constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      this.path = this.location.path();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx. I used this method to disable the navigation schematic for a single page.